# Pass additional object to 3rd-party callback

Tags: javascript, canvas, callback

I am working on screenshot taking script. For taking screenshot I am using `html2canvas` lib. Thing is when screenshot is eventually taken and `onrendered` callback is called  I have to do some additional handling and for that purpose I need to be able to get some arguments, which I was using before.

```
function onMessageReceived(event){
        ...
    if (dataObj.screenshot)
    {
        takeScreenshot(dataObj); 
    }
}
```

Screenshot taking function:

```
function takeScreenshot(dataObj) {
    html2canvas($('body'),{
        onrendered: function (canvas) {                     
            var imgString = canvas.toDataURL("screenshot.png"); 
            window.open(imgString);  
            //do some additional handling here using dataObj    
        }
    });
}
```

Is there some good straight-forward solution for it? I mean, without using global vars or saving this `dataObj` on the disk.

Comment: That scope has access to `dataObj` already... have you not already tried using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way scopes in JS work, `dataObj` is already available in the scope for your `takeScreenshot` function because you passed it in from the other function. So all you need to do is use it in the callback. Here's how you would alert the value of the `screenshot` attribute on your `dataObj`.

```
function takeScreenshot(dataObj) {
    html2canvas($('body'),{
        onrendered: function (canvas) {                     
            var imgString = canvas.toDataURL("screenshot.png"); 
            window.open(imgString);  
            alert(dataObj.screenshot);
        }
    });
}
```